# export data into webpage with vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am having trouble trying to get data into a website page. The page is a asp. I want to enter information by a userform. At this stage I am just trying to access the webpage fields to enter the data. I have very little knowledge of excel vba but I know it can be a good tool for me to use.

The outcome I am after is to be able to find street addresses in particular area codes. If I can't automate it I will have to do it by hand which will be tedious and time consuming. The data will be stored in excel.

The webpage I want to interact with is on the local appraisal site. My question is exactly what would be the best route. I tried using the getElementsByTagName form, and ID but It does not work or I am using the wrong method.

The Itfind string is to see if it is accessing the field in the html code I want. Yet it still comes back empty. I tried a for loop it did not work.

All answers are helpful. Please give example so I can understand.

Thanks

Here is the code below I am starting with.

```
Sub Addrfind()
Dim IE As New InternetExplorer

    IE.navigate ""

    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    Set doc = IE.document
    Dim Itfind As String
    Itfind = doc.getElementsByTagName("Form").Item(1)
```

Here are the slim version of the fields I am trying to manipulate. 
I want to enter data into the **value=""**s. I know the initial method was off but need some direction to correct this.

```
<table>...</table>
<div Class="">...</div>
<table>...</table>
<table>...</table>
<table>...</table>
<form name="frm1" id="frm1" action="Ad.asp" method="post"></form>
<tbody>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
       <form name="frm2" id="frm2" action="Ad.asp" method="get"></form>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="sub_header">Street Name</td>
        <td><input name="stname" type="text" size="20" maxlength="20" value=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="sub_header">Zip</td>
        <td><input name="zip" type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" value=""></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: MSDN could be a good point you can start with. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementsbytagname(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: can you please show some sample page to extract content